# Difference Between Remove & RemoveAt in Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

What is the difference between `Remove` & `RemoveAt` in **`ListBox`**?

Comment: What kind of listbox? What UI framework are you using? What are you trying to do?

Comment: There's still not enough information in your edit for this question to be answerable. C# doesn't have a ListBox.

Comment: Excuse me , I'm just starting out in listbox And I did not know more about listbox .And its about Visual Studio 2010 asp.net 4

Comment: I try to add item form list box1 to list box2.then I want to remove the selected item from list box1.eg..for (int x = 0; x < ListBox1.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                if (ListBox1.Items[x].Selected == true)
                {
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[x].Text);
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[x].Text);
                }
            }

Answer (score 7):

Well, first of all, if you have a `ListBox listBox;`, then `listBox` has no method `Remove` or `RemoveAt`. It would be `listBox.Items.Remove(...)` or `listBox.Items.RemoveAt(...)`. I assume here that you are using the `ListBox` in `System.Windows.Forms`.

Now, the difference between `Remove` and `RemoveAt` is that **one takes an item to remove** from the list, and **one takes an index**.

To make it more clear, let's create an `List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 });`. Since everything **is zero-based in C#**, the value in the list at index 0 is `10`, the value at index 1 is `20`, etc.

`List`s, just like `ObjectCollection`s, have `Remove` and `RemoveAt` methods. In the case of our simple list, calling `list.Remove(20);` will remove the first occurence of `20` that it finds in the list. `list` will end up with the elements `{ 10, 30, 40 }` since `20` was removed.

If instead of calling `Remove` on `list`, we called `list.RemoveAt(1);`, it would do the same thing to the list. We are removing the element of the list *at* index `1`: in this case, `20`.

Answer (score 0):

I am calculating the difference between RemoveAt and Remove function. Checkout the following snippet:

```
       {
           while(ShowListBox.Items.Count != 0)
           {

               for(int i = 0; i < ShowListBox.Items.Count; i++)
               {
                   ShowListBox.Items.Remove(ShowListBox.Items[i].ToString());
               }
               while (ShowListBox.Items.Count > 0)
               {
                   ShowListBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
               }

           }

       }
```

In the above code all data gets deleted(text, number and any sign inside listbox)

This fails for when using the Remove function to RemoveAt.